# calculating regression sum of square in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

Here is [sample data](https://web.archive.org/web/20230112230109/https://online.stat.psu.edu/onlinecourses/sites/stat501/files/data/iqsize.txt):

```
        brainIQ <- 
      read.table (file= "https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/
  onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/iqsize.txt",
     head = TRUE)
```

I am trying to fit multiple linear regression.

```
mylm <- lm(PIQ ~  Brain + Height + Weight, data = brainIQ)
anova(mylm)
```

Default function anova in R provides sequential sum of squares (type I) sum of square.

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PIQ
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
Brain      1  2697.1 2697.09  6.8835 0.01293 *
Height     1  2875.6 2875.65  7.3392 0.01049 *
Weight     1     0.0    0.00  0.0000 0.99775  
Residuals 34 13321.8  391.82                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I belief, thus the SS are Brain, Height | Brain, Weight | (Brain, Weight) and residuals respectively.

Using package car we can also get type II sum of square.

```
library(car)
Anova(mylm, type="II")
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: PIQ
           Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
Brain      5239.2  1 13.3716 0.0008556 ***
Height     1934.7  1  4.9378 0.0330338 *  
Weight        0.0  1  0.0000 0.9977495    
Residuals 13321.8 34                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here sum of squares are like: Brian | (Height, Weight), Height | (Brain, Weight), Weight | (Brain, Height).

Which look pretty like Mintab output:

[image]

My question is how can I calculate the regression row in the above table in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found matrix approach to solve this problem:

Here we can calculate SSR and Total sum of square.

```
    # Y matrix 
    Y <- as.matrix(brainIQ$PIQ, ncol=1)
    n= nrow(Y)
    J = matrix(1, nrow=n, ncol=n)
    # Total sum of Square 
    SSTO = t(Y) %*% Y - (1/n)*t(Y)%*%J%*%Y 
    X <- as.matrix(cbind(1, brainIQ[,-1]))
    b = solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
# regression sum of square 
    SSR = t(b)%*%t(X)%*%Y - (1/n)%*%t(Y)%*%J%*%Y
> SSR
         [,1]
[1,] 5572.744

> SSTO
         [,1]
[1,] 18894.55
```

Here - **SSR(Brain, Height, Weight) = SSR(Brain) + SSR(Height|Brain) + SSR (Weight|Height, Brain)** - which is actually sequential sum of square output from anova.

```
mylm <- lm(PIQ ~  Brain + Height + Weight, data = brainIQ)

# SSR(Brain, Height, Weight)
sum(anova(mylm)[-4,2])

# Total sum of square 
sum(anova(mylm)[,2])
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SS(Regression) = SS(Total) - S(Residual)
```

You can get SS(Total) by:

```
SSTotal <- var( brainIQ$PIQ ) * (nrow(brainIQ)-1)
    SSE     <- sum( mylm$resid^2 )
SSreg   <- SSTotal - SSE
```

The degrees of freedom for the "Regression" row are the sum of the degrees of freedom for the corresponding components of the Regression (in this case: Brain, Height, and Weight).

Then to get the rest:

```
dfE   <- mylm$df.residual
dfReg <- nrow(brainIQ) - 1 - dfE
MSreg <- SSreg / dfReg
MSE   <- SSE / dfE
Fstat <- MSreg / MSE
pval  <- pf( Fstat , dfReg, dfE , lower.tail=FALSE )
```

Comment: Note also that `deviance(mylm)` will directly report the SSE.

Comment: Would like to add that in many texts, SSE is used to denote explained sum of squares (your SSreg and SS(Regression)). Those texts use SSR for residual sum of squares (your SSE and SS(Residual)).

Answer (score 2):

If you have built a linear model already, you can compute the regression sum of squares with one line. Using your model:

```
sum((mylm$fitted.values - mean(mylm$fitted.values))^2)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the mean of the response is equal to the mean of the fitted values.

**UPDATE**: As @whuber pointed out, the line above assumes that the model includes a constant ("intercept") in the span of its design matrix. The line below does not make this assumption and will work more generally:

```
sum((mylm$fitted.values - mean(mylm$model$y))^2)
```

Comment: +1 -- but we should make a point of insisting that the model include a constant ("intercept") in the span of its design matrix, for otherwise this solution fails.

Comment: Good catch. "mean of the response" is not equal to the mean of the fitted values when forcing regression through the origin.